# how to change pie chart colors of JFreeChart?

Tags: jfreechart

how to customize the colors of JFreeChart graphic.
lets see my java code :

```
private StreamedContent chartImage ;

public void init(){
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("title", createDataset(), true, true, false);
    File chartFile = new File("dynamichart");
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(chartFile, jfreechart, 375, 300);
    chartImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream( chartFile), "image/png");
}

public PieDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
          dataset.setValue("J-2", 10);
          dataset.setValue("J-1", 15);
          dataset.setValue("J", 50);
          dataset.setValue("J+1", 20);
          dataset.setValue("J+2", 15);
    return dataset;
}
```

html page :

```
<p:graphicImage id="MyImage" value="#{beanCreateImage.chartImage}" />
```

Comment: Do you want to change each pie color or what ?

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? It's hardly possible for people to give a correct answer if you don't say what you want. (Asking for pie doesn't get you apple pie for sure, there are a lot of pies.) ;-)

Comment: I want to change the color of each pie. thank you

Comment: @berber5 Then my answer should help you out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the color of single pieces like this:

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("title", createDataset(), true, true, false);
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setSectionPaint("J+1", Color.black);
plot.setSectionPaint("J-1", new Color(120, 0, 120));
// or do this, if you are using an older version of JFreeChart:
//plot.setSectionPaint(1, Color.black);
//plot.setSectionPaint(3, new Color(120, 0, 120));
```

So with your code, all the pies are colored automatically, after my code changes, the `J-1` and `J+1` have a fixed color, the rest gets automatically colored.

[image: Comparison]

Comment: how to see the result of new Color(227, 26, 28),

Comment: if `plot.setSectionPaint(String id, Color col)` does not exist, you are using a quite old version of JFreeChart. And yes, then you can simply access the individual sections with their index (which is deprecated in newer versions of JFreeChart).

Comment: What do you mean by *see the result of 'new Color(227, 26, 28)'*? You mean like a [Color Picker](http://www.colorpicker.com/)?

Comment: I found that  new Color(int x, int y, int z) means : x : red, y: green and z: blue.

Comment: Ah ok, you can look that stuff up in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html). If you are using a newer IDE like eclipse or netbeans, you can hover over the code (`Color` in this case) with your mouse and you will see additional information.

Answer (score 10):

To set the colous for a chart you can implement the `DrawingSupplier` inferface in this case I've used `DefaultDrawingSupplier`:

```
public class ChartDrawingSupplier extends DefaultDrawingSupplier  {

    public Paint[] paintSequence;
    public int paintIndex;
    public int fillPaintIndex;

    {
        paintSequence =  new Paint[] {
                new Color(227, 26, 28),
                new Color(000,102, 204),
                new Color(102,051,153),
                new Color(102,51,0),
                new Color(156,136,48),
                new Color(153,204,102),
                new Color(153,51,51),
                new Color(102,51,0),
                new Color(204,153,51),
                new Color(0,51,0),
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getNextPaint() {
        Paint result
        = paintSequence[paintIndex % paintSequence.length];
        paintIndex++;
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public Paint getNextFillPaint() {
        Paint result
        = paintSequence[fillPaintIndex % paintSequence.length];
        fillPaintIndex++;
        return result;
    }   
}
```

Then include this code in your `init()' method

```java
JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("title", createDataset(), true, true, false);
Plot plot = jfreechart.getPlot();
plot.setDrawingSupplier(new ChartDrawingSupplier());
...
```

Comment: how to define the color of Color(227, 26, 28)?

Comment: @berber5 new Color(227, 26, 28) is just a way to define a colour by setting the Red, Green and Blue values.  You shold pick a set of colours that suit your application, you can find some examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp) and [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/consistent-colors-for-your-site-all-you-need-to-know-about-web-safe-colors.html)

Comment: +1 Interesting, I did not know about the 'DrawingSupplier' classes. Although in his case, I would prefer my way.

Comment: You might want to consider using a DefaultDrawingSupplier constructor and call through to `super()` as you can provide that Paint sequence without having to override any methods yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the colors according to the labels while getting the data from the dataset:

```
// Add custom colors
        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataset.getItemCount(); i++) {
            if(dataset.getKey(i).equals("J+1")){ 
                plot.setSectionPaint(i, Color.black);
            }
        }
```

You can also use a switch-case statement or the one you prefer.