# Change StackedBarChart Colors based on key values

Tags: colors, jfreechart, pie-chart, stackedbarseries

I would like to modify stackedBarChart's colors using key values. I know how to do this for piecharts, but am unable to accomplish the same for stackedBarCharts.

For piecharts, essentially my approach is similar to the answer stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009349/how-to-change-pie-chart-colors-of-jfreechart)

The lines of code to note are:

```
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setSectionPaint("J+1", Color.black);
plot.setSectionPaint("J-1", new Color(120, 0, 120));
```

However for StackedBarChart, I am unsure of how to do it, essentially I have to modify the existing jfreechart code below:

```
 public static JFreeChart createStackedBarChart(final String title,
                        final CategoryDataset dataset) {

                JFreeChart sectorChart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart(title, "",
                                "", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, false, false);

                CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) sectorChart.getPlot();
                formatCategoryPlot(plot);
                sectorChart.getLegend().setBorder(0, 0, 0, 0);
                sectorChart.setBorderVisible(false);
                sectorChart.setBorderPaint(Color.white);
                plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
                StackedBarRenderer renderer = (StackedBarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();


                return Chart;

        }
```

**So my question really is, is there a equivalent of**

```
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setSectionPaint("J+1", Color.black);
```

**for stackedBarCharts? If yes, how can I use it?**

I can see from web resources that there is something about setSeriesPaint, but that seems to be changing colors based on index. I would like to change colors based on the labels, such as "J+1".

Answer (score 1):

You can override the renderer's `getItemPaint()` method, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002959/230513).

[image]

Comment: thanks. The code doesn't show how to define colors based on section labels...can you help elaborate on that?

Comment: You might also look at a custom `DrawingSupplier`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16754801/230513).